# RabbitMQ: re-consume non-acked message in fanout exchange

Tags: php, rabbitmq

Here is my problem. I want to create a toy application in [Publish/Subscribe](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-three-php.html) fashion, I took that one as an example. But I want to implement my consumers with an acknowledgements. I expect the following behavior: after one of my consumers dies, I run that script in a console again, and the message gets processed.

Here is a code for a publisher:

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AMQPStreamConnection;
use PhpAmqpLib\Message\AMQPMessage;

$connection = new AMQPStreamConnection('localhost', 5672, 'guest', 'guest');
$channel = $connection->channel();

$channel->exchange_declare('logs', 'fanout', false, true, false);

$data = implode(' ', array_slice($argv, 1));
if(empty($data)) $data = "info: Hello World!";
$msg = new AMQPMessage($data);

$channel->basic_publish($msg, 'logs');

echo " [x] Sent ", $data, "\n";

$channel->close();
$connection->close();
```

And here is a code for a subscriber:

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AMQPStreamConnection;

$connection = new AMQPStreamConnection('localhost', 5672, 'guest', 'guest');
$channel = $connection->channel();

$channel->exchange_declare('logs', 'fanout', false, true, false);

$channel->queue_declare("queue1", false, true, true, false);

$channel->queue_bind("queue1", 'logs');

echo ' [*] Waiting for logs. To exit press CTRL+C', "\n";

$callback = function($msg){
    echo ' [x] ', $msg->body, "\n";
    die();
    $msg->delivery_info['channel']->basic_ack($msg->delivery_info['delivery_tag']);
};

$channel->basic_consume("queue1", '', false, false, false, false, $callback);

while(count($channel->callbacks)) {
    $channel->wait();
}

$channel->close();
$connection->close();
```

When I run it, `[x] info: Hello World!` is displayed in a subscriber's console, than I expect that message is not acknowledged since the script simply dies. After I run it again, there are no messages consumed. And rabbitMQ web-panel shows there are no unacked messages as well.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you declared an [exclusive queue](https://www.rabbitmq.com/queues.html). It's deleted once the connection is lost. So when you pushed Ctrl + C, queue was dropped, and when you run that script again, there was a new queue with no messages in it. So you need to declare a queue non-exclusive:

```
$channel->queue_declare("queue1", false, true, false, false);
```